# Join tree tables and get last status according date hierarchy

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have following tree tables

Table  soldier

```
ID   |   NAME 
---------------
22   |   Franck 
23   |   Paul 
24   |   Bill
```

Table soldier_status_history

```
soldier_id   |            date_record       |     soldier_status 
-----------------------------------------------------------------          
22           |        2012-12-07 18:09:58   |          37 
22           |        2012-12-08 18:10:11   |          38 
22           |        2012-12-10 18:20:25   |          41 
23           |        2011-08-17 23:59:10   |          37 
23           |        2011-08-19 23:59:11   |          38 
23           |        2011-08-22 00:00:00   |          41  
23           |        2011-08-25 12:00:22   |          38   
24           |        2011-08-24 19:18:43   |          37  
24           |        2011-08-29 19:18:44   |          38
```

Table soldier_values

```
id   |   key 
----------------
37   |   onduty 
38   |   available 
40   |   vacation 
41   |   ill
```

Is it possible to be made a select that will join them and will return me only records from table soldier_status_history that soldier_status for last date_record for particular soldier is not “vacation” or “ill”

I mean for this person named “Paul” we have tree records but last one is record that he is ill that way this person should not be displayed until its status is not changed.

```
23      |        2011-08-17 23:59:10    |   37 
23      |        2011-08-19 23:59:11    |   38 
23      |        2011-08-22 00:00:00    |   41
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
soldier s
left join 
(select 
     soldier_id, 
     max(date_record) maxDate_record
   from soldier_status_history 
   group by soldier_id
) s2 
    on (s.id=s2.soldier_id)
left join soldier_status_history s3 
    on (s2.soldier_id=s3.soldier_id) and (s2.maxDate_record=s3.date_record)

where s3.soldier_status not in (40,41)
```

Comment: Thank you too for the instant answer will try to fit in my case.

Comment: As addition to say this solution is faster for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  h.*
FROM Soldier s 
INNER JOIN soldier_status_history h ON s.ID = h.soldier_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Soldier_id, MAX(date_record) latestDate
  FROM soldier_status_history 
  GROUP BY soldier_id
) l  ON h.soldier_id = s.ID
    AND DATE(l.latestDate) = DATE(h.date_record);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffc29/2)

This will give you:

```
| SOLDIER_ID |                     DATE_RECORD | SOLDIER_STATUS |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|         22 | December, 10 2012 18:20:25+0000 |             41 |
|         23 |   August, 25 2011 12:00:22+0000 |             38 |
|         24 |   August, 29 2011 19:18:44+0000 |             38 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very instant answer, i tried and it works.